# Node Express js in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've created an expressjs app and I'm trying to deploy it in Google Cloud Functions. 
I've developed the app on my own and then followed this [guide](http://labs.roitraining.com/labs/gcp-node-express-cloud-functions/index.html#7) to attach it to the gCloud function service.
Basically, I created an `index.js` file in the root of my project

```
var app = require('./app');

function App(req,res) {
    if (!req.url) {
        req.url = '/';
        req.path = '/';
    }
    return app(req,res);
}

var converter = App;

module.exports = {
    converter
};
```

ps. I left the name converter to be compliant with the guide in order to test, I'll update it as soon as it works ;D

My project looks like this now

```
- myAppProject
--- index.js
--- app.js
--- package.json
--- someFolderWithCode
------ someFile.js
```

I zipped the code and used the gCloud console (aka the webapp) to upload the zip and defined the function `converter`, which is the same exported in my `index.js`. 
The problem is that I get this error

```
Function load error: File index.js or function.js that is expected to define function doesn't exist in the root directory.
```

I cannot understand what am I missing.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue. 
I zipped `myAppProject`, while I should have zipped all files contained in it. After that it accepted the `index.js` file.